# Jquery не исполняется

Tags: php, html, jquery

здравствуйте! Задача такая:
в бд есть поля:id,content и вставлено единственное значение:id-1,а content-"привет". В поле ввожу цифру, нажимаю на кнопку,отправляется запрос на сервер и должен получать в поле вывода значение из поля id, а внизу этого поля- значение поля content и введенное значение. Например ввёл 23 и в поле получаю 1, а внизу текст "привет 23".
 С сайта http://www.sdelaysite.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-dlya-nachinayushhix загрузил исходники  и дамп бд ,запускаю но при клике на кнопке ничего не происходит.

**Jquery.html** выгдядит так:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function runajax()
    {
        var inp0 = $("#inp0").val();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: "key=" + inp0,
              url: "ajax2.php",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data)
              {
                $("#inp1").val(data.id);
                var temp = data.content + " " + data.key;
                $("#p1").text(temp);
              }
            })
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn0").click(runajax);
        });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Входные значения:</p>
        <p><input type="text" id="inp0"> <input type="button" value="Отправить запрос" id="btn0"></p>
        <p>Результаты обработки запроса:</p>
        <p><input type="text" id="inp1"></p>
        <p id="p1"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

а файл **файл ajax2.php** так:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST["key"])) $key = $_POST["key"];
if (!mysql_connect(localhost, root, root)) 
{
    exit;
}
mysql_select_db("test");
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_table");
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$res['key'] = $key;
echo json_encode($res);
```

проверил на простой скрипт- он исполняется:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>-->
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      alert("hello");
      })
    </script>
    </head>

    </html>
```

файлы лежат в одном каталоге.
в файле ajax2.php условие if (!mysql_connect(localhost,root,root)) поменял на if (!mysql_connect('localhost','root','')) но ничего не меняется. можете переписать исходник и дамп и посмотреть?! 
И еще,в веб-программировании опыта почти нет и не знаю как делается пошаговая отладка? работаю в notepad++

Comment: Выкиньте *редактор текста*, поставьте *IDE*. Например, PHPStorm. Ваша жизнь сразу изменится к лучшему, на лысине заколосятся волосы, а девушки начнут приставать с неприличными предложениями.

Answer (score 1):

Замените:

```
<p><input type="text" id="inp0"> <input type="button" value="Отправить запрос" id="btn0"></p>
```

на

```
<p><input type="text" id="inp0"> <input type="button" value="Отправить запрос" id="btn0" onclick="runajax(); return false;"></p>
```

Затем:

уберите

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn0").click(runajax);
        });
```

После:
Проверьте нет ли ошибок в файле error.log (apache), запущен ли mysql.

В качестве дополнительной проверки можно временно заменить файл ajax2.php на следующий:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'id' => 'Success',
    'content' => 'Success content',
    'key' => 'Success key-' . $_REQUEST['key']
);

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

В Вашем коде очень много недочетов и ошибок. Думаю Вам стоит найти другой пример для разбора.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177705/grayhoax  переделал код как вы сказали- ноль внимания!   ошибок в файле error.log нет,   mysql запущен.   Антивирус и skype не установлен.  Код выглядит рабочим- на видео автора видно, что код работает.

Comment: Нажмите F12, если используете chrome или firefox и посмотрите какие ошибки вываливаются. А ещё лучше, запакуйте свои скрипты и пришлите ссылку на архив.

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177705/grayhoax  архив здесь: http://files.webfile.ru/336f2892ce8da1431a2e7352647aafcc

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177705/grayhoax    извиняюсь, забил дамп бд: http://files.webfile.ru/38760bf42e02c6141d4c3ffbadeb5afa

Comment: Ура. заработал в IE . причина-jquery-2.1.4 поменял на jquery-1.6.1 (версия explorer-а старая 8.0 ).